# Executing an query inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am executing an sql query inside a for loop, the function that is executing the query is an asynchronous operation. So I am wrapping the asynchronous operation in an immediate invoking function.

```
for(var k in bizValuesObj){
    if( existingCountries.hasOwnProperty(bizValuesObj[k]["country"]) ){
        country_id = existingCountries[bizValuesObj[k]["country"]];
    }

    var productName = bizValuesObj[k]["product"];
    var bizTypes = bizValuesObj[k]["bizTypes"];
    var getproductIdQuery = "SELECT `id` FROM `product` WHERE name = ? AND country_id = ?";

    (function(){
        connection.query(getproductIdQuery, [productName, country_id], function(err, result){
            if(err){
                console.error("Error getting product id:", err.stack);
            }
            product_id = result[0].id;
            for(var j= 0; j < bizTypes.length; j++){
                var temp = [];
                temp.push(bizTypes[j]);
                temp.push(country_id);
                temp.push(product_id);
                bizValues.push(temp);
            }
        });
    })(k);
}
```

At the moment, I am unsure why the **bizValues** doesn't get populated until the main loop has finished. I am trying to populate **bizValues** for every value of k.

Comment: The IIFE doesn't magically make it synchronous, it's still async, and completes "some time later", most likely when the loop has finished

Comment: @adeneo how can i approach this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to alter this code and use promise.all [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

In short Promise.all takes an array of promises and executes the promise only when all the async data has been fetched. One advantage/disadvantage of Promise.all is the catch block is invoked the moment you hit an error in any single iterable

```
for(var k in bizValuesObj){
    if( existingCountries.hasOwnProperty(bizValuesObj[k]["country"]) ){
        country_id = existingCountries[bizValuesObj[k]["country"]];
    }

    var productName = bizValuesObj[k]["product"];
    var bizTypes = bizValuesObj[k]["bizTypes"];
    var getproductIdQuery = "SELECT `id` FROM `product` WHERE name = ? AND country_id = ?";
    // Async handling from here
    const promiseArray = []
    promiseArray.push(connection.query(getproductIdQuery, [productName, country_id])); // <- This function is a promise
} 

Promise.all(promiseArray).then((response) => {
    // your response after all async fetches
}).catch((error) => handle error)
```

Now in the success handler your can process your data further.

Comment: i just tried your recommended method, but its still doing the same as before. My objective is to execute the query for every country_id, so basically for every kth value. With the above solution the final response only has the last element

Answer (score 0):

Your code is asynchronous, it will get populated but after some time. You should try using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to solve your problem. You can make an array of promise and then call each one of them parallely/serially. I would recommend using [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). But you would have to handle cases where a promise fails. refer to the code below

```
function getPromise(getproductIdQuery){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            connection.query(getproductIdQuery, [productName, country_id], function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    console.error("Error getting product id:", err.stack);
                    reject(err);
                }
                product_id = result[0].id;
                for(var j= 0; j < bizTypes.length; j++){
                    var temp = [];
                    temp.push(bizTypes[j]);
                    temp.push(country_id);
                    temp.push(product_id);
                    bizValues.push(temp);
                }
                resolve(true);
            }
    })
}

let promiseArray = [];
for(var k in bizValuesObj){
    if( existingCountries.hasOwnProperty(bizValuesObj[k]["country"]) ){
        country_id = existingCountries[bizValuesObj[k]["country"]];
    }

    var productName = bizValuesObj[k]["product"];
    var bizTypes = bizValuesObj[k]["bizTypes"];
    var getproductIdQuery = "SELECT `id` FROM `product` WHERE name = ? AND country_id = ?";
    promiseArray.push(getPromise(getproductIdQuery));
} 

Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function(){
    // here you would find temp array populated
})
```

Comment: I tried your solution and i do get a repsonse, but the country_id only refers to the last country in the temp array